# Find an assignment discarding a subset of possible assignments

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, matching, bipartite-matching, assignment-problem

We have a $N \times N$ cost matrix where the cost denotes the amount incurred for assigning a worker to a task.

The number of possible assignments is $N!$. Let us call this set of all possible assignments as $Z$.

Assume we have a subset $S$ of assignments from the $N!$ possible assignments.

How can I get one best cost assignment (optimal assignment) from $Z - S$ ?

Comment: Sorry, that wouldn't be right. I think you have not understood the problem. $S$ is the set of discarded assignments. It is not the set of edges of an assignment, rather a set of multiple assignments. Similarly, Z is not the set of edges of an assignment, rather it is the set of all possible $N!$ assignments.

Comment: I see now. Thanks for clarification!